# Adding unbound localizable label to quick create form

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

Is there a way to add unbound label (for guidance purposes) to quick-create form? Only way I have found is to create a web resource like:

```
<html>
  <body>
   <label>some text</label>
  </body>
</html>
```

And include it on a form. This seems to work for main forms; as for localization - it can be done like:

```
<html>
  <body>
   <label id="label"></label>
   <script>// fetch and setup label content</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The issue is - there is no such option for quick create forms. Also it seems overly complex. Is there a simpler way how to include simple label/text for guidance purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way I could think of is using `setFormNotification` and it works in Quick Create form also. You can fetch & setup whatever you want for localization.

```
if (Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType() === 1) {
    Xrm.Page.ui.setFormNotification("Note: Please do so and so", "INFO", "someUniqueName");
}
```

[image]

Also, when you fill the attribute description in Entity customizations that text will show as a tooltip on mouseover on form control label (Thought of mentioning, ignore if it's not useful for you).

Another option is like using Multiline textbox or Textarea control as a placeholder to show guidance text. Make it read-only & don't display the label in the form.

Comment: The setFormNotification is by far the simplest - I should have though of that. For the record there is yet another way (at least if u use 9.0 CRM with UCI interface) - create custom control that renders that label.